# App crash due to Fatal Exception: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException Index: 0, Size: 0

Tags: java, firebase, android-studio, crashlytics

I developed a quiz app that fetched data from firestore. I tested it on several devices. It worked finely & has no crashes at all. I launched it 2 weeks ago.
**According to the firebase crashlytics the error is,**

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
   at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:437)
   at com.supun.mcqapp.QuestionsActivity.setQuestion(QuestionsActivity.java:151)
   at com.supun.mcqapp.QuestionsActivity.access$100(QuestionsActivity.java:43)
   at com.supun.mcqapp.QuestionsActivity$1.onComplete(QuestionsActivity.java:105)
   at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzj.run(:4)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6846)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:504)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

I asked for a solution from several. I can't figure out the problem and how to correct it. Please help.

If you want to check the full code please drop me a comment.

> isSuccessful and getResults produce arrylist size = 0, when debugging.

```js
private void getQuestionList() {

        questionList.clear();


        firestore.collection("QUIZ").document("CAT" + String.valueOf(category_id)).collection("SET" + String.valueOf(setNo))
                .get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                Map<String, QueryDocumentSnapshot> questList = new ArrayMap<>();


                if (task.isSuccessful()){  //isSuccessful and getResults produce arrylist size =0 when I debugging. I don't know how to correct it.
                    QuerySnapshot questions = task.getResult();
                    for (QueryDocumentSnapshot doc : questions){
                        questionList.add(new Question(doc.getString("QUESTION"),
                                doc.getString("A"),
                                doc.getString("B"),
                                doc.getString("C"),
                                doc.getString("D"),
                                Integer.valueOf(doc.getString("ANSWER"))
                                ));
                    } setQuestion();
                }else {
                    Toast.makeText(QuestionsActivity.this,task.getException().getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
        
    }


private void setQuestion()
    {
        timer.setText(String.valueOf(40));

        question.setText(questionList.get(0).getQuestion());  //This is 151 line.
        option1.setText(questionList.get(0).getOptionA());
        option2.setText(questionList.get(0).getOptionB());
        option3.setText(questionList.get(0).getOptionC());
        option4.setText(questionList.get(0).getOptionD());

        qCount.setText(String.valueOf(1)+"/"+ String.valueOf(questionList.size()));

        startTimer();

        quesNum = 0;
    }
```

Comment: It'd be easier to help if you isolated the line code around where the IndexOutOfBoundsException is happening. It looks like you might have changed the code before posting the snippet because the line numbers from the stack trace don't seem to make sense.

Comment: @WilliamHammond I isolate the code with error. you can check it at the bottom of the question. thank you.

Comment: If you encounter problems, it's best to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when posting a question. You posted almost **400 (four hundred)** lines of code for this issue. That's a lot for people to parse and try to debug online. Please edit your question and isolate the problem, in that way you increase your chances of being helped.

Comment: @AlexMamo I shorten the code. Please look into it. when I debug the code, isSuccessful and getResults lines produce arrylist size = 0. I don't know how to correct it. if anyone wants to look into the full code please let me know.

Comment: If you check the size of the list after the for-loop, is the size still 0?

Comment: @AlexMamo after the for loop, the size =1

Comment: So you have only one result in the database, right?

Comment: No. The questionList has 10 questions. So the size is 10. App visualize the questions one by one. If player select a answer or after 40 seconds, second question appears.

Comment: @AlexMamo sorry I mistakenly seen questionList size as 1. It is size = 0 when debugging. But questList ArrayMap produce size =0 after for loop. Will the problem solve after removing ArryMap? (App works without arrymap.)